# High speed (EDR) data transfer possible with HC-05 bluetooth module?

Tags: bluetooth, bandwidth

From what I understand, the popular HC-05 bluetooth module is using a [CSR BC417](http://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Wireless/Bluetooth/CSR-BC417-datasheet.pdf) controller part, which supports EDR for 2/3 Mbps modes, also up to 3Mbaud UART interface for the mcu.

Assuming the mcu is fast enough, is it possible to achieve the EDR speeds with the HC-05 module?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the hc-05 supports EDR and the specs can be seen [here](http://www.robotshop.com/media/files/pdf/rb-ite-12-bluetooth_hc05.pdf). Actually achieving those speeds might be difficult, but take a look [here as well](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=337424.0)